# Getting a strange result when using hibernate criteria API, using restrictions and order by

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

So I have written the hibernate method using the criteria api like this

```
@Override
public List<UBSIvrDetail> getIvrDetails(String caseNo, Date tradeDate) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    List<UBSIvrDetail> dataList = null;

    try {
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(UBSIvrDetail.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("caseNo", caseNo));
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("tradeDate", tradeDate));
        cr.addOrder(Order.asc("caseNo"));
        cr.addOrder(Order.asc("socSecNo"));
        cr.addOrder(Order.asc("fundId"));

        dataList = cr.list();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

When I look at the sql of this using show sql and put it into data base i see 690 unique values and its all good. But when I inspect the list it is returning the same row 690 times. Am I missing something here? Totally lost on why that would be.
Thanks in advance for any help. Namaste

Comment: So you're saying, when you print the list out to a terminal or somewhere, you're getting the same data 690 times, or are you inspecting what it's doing and seeing the same object reference?

Comment: @Makoto Yes this list is returning the same value 690 times (repeating the same value) while printing in the console which is incorrect. Whereas if I put the same sql equivalent code (that i got from turning the show sql property on) in the data base and execute it it returns 690 different values